# Edit text of UIButton with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipickerview

I would like the user to be able to change the title of a button this is a hardcoded example of what I intend to do:

```
   [myButton setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, I would rather prompt the user with a UIPicker, and allow the user to choose from many options in order to change the title.

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;

   if ([sender.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
      NSLog(@"user has clicked the button%@", sender.view);
      UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)sender.view;
       UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
       myButton.titleLabel = picker;

   }

}
```

At this point I see an error `*assignment to readonly property` Is it possible to use the UIPickerView in conjunction with the setTitle property of UIButton? If so how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is obvious:

titleLabel is a UILabel property of the UIButton class, and it is read-only (you cannot set it to another value). You need to use its label's text property instead:

```
myButton.titleLabel.text = @"some text";
```

and not:

```
myButton.titleLabel = picker;
```

or

```
myButton.titleLabel.text = picker;
```

because picker is not an NSString object.

Let me explain in a minute how to implement this...

In your View Controller class, create a property (I recommend to do it in the private interface), and also implement the UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate protocols:

```
@interface PPMyViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *pickerView;

@end
```

Now, use lazy instantiation for the pickerView property:

```
- (UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    if (!_pickerView)
    {
        _pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
        _pickerView.dataSource = self;
        _pickerView.delegate = self;
    }

    return _pickerView;
}

Make sure you add to the main view, you can do it in the viewDidLoad method:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.view addSubview:self.pickerView];
}


And implement most of the 2 protocols methods:

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource Methods

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 10;
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate Methods

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return 200;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 50;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d", row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"Row %d selected", row);
//    myButton.titleLabel.text = @"text you need depending on row selection";
}
```

Notice that my code will make the UIPickerView visible at the bottom all the times. You may hide/unhide it as needed. Or better, use animation to position it off-screen instead of hiding.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this like you attempt to. What you need to do is listen to the user's tap of the button, and then present a picker to the user.

There are open source controls that can simplify this, such as [ActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0).